# How to save a file in zyanaddsubfx

Tags: files, midi

I am trying to save a file in Zynaddsubfx so that I can record a MIDI file. Does anyone know how to do that? Additionally, how do you open the file once it is saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot record to a MIDI in Zynaddsubfx, as it is not a sequencer, but only a "simple" synth. You can however, record to a WAV file. If you want a MIDI, you will have to hook up Zynaddsubfx to `seq24` or a similar sequencer program, create a song, and save to MIDI from there. You will need to hook up Zynaddsubfx and the sequencer again, to play the song, as playback with other software may result in slightly different instruments being used, and thus a different sound than what you were hoping to record.

Comment: Is possible to record a wave file and then export it to an MP3? All I am trying to do is have the capability to burn a cd if I wish, or play it on a player. Thanks again.

Comment: You can record to a WAV file, and then use another program to convert it to MP3. There's nothing in Zynaddsubfx to convert to MP3. Audacity would work well for it, though.

Comment: One of the items in the menus is "Record to WAV…" Just pick that.

Answer (score 0):

Some details to save to wav on Ubuntu 20.04, zynaddsubfs 3.0.5, the interface is atrocious:

```
zynaddsubfx -O alsa
```

then:

- Misc
- Switch User interface mode (moves to "advanced mode")
- Record
- Choose wav file

After this, the record button becomes enabled.

So you can now open a virtual keyboard with the vK button, and it then records the wav.

However, stopping the recording did not actually stop it for me, I have to actually close Zyn for it to stop.

Also I don't know how to automate this.

Hopefully the new interface zyn-fusion will be easier to use, and will someday get ported into debian.

To get a midi file, you could use vmpk as mentioned here: [Save as MIDI when playing from VMPK & QSynth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/709673/save-as-midi-when-playing-from-vmpk-qsynth/1298231#1298231) You can plug it into zynaddsubfx exactly as it is plugged into fluidsynth as explained at: [Virtual MIDI Piano Keyboard setup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34391/virtual-midi-piano-keyboard-setup/1298026#1298026)

Related: https://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=229567

**LMMS ZynAddSubFX plugin**

Just want to say that this is a really simple way to make MIDI tracks with Zyn. It just works, and can export to wav/ogg. You just launch LMMS and drag the ZynAddSubFX plugin into the timeline, and you can then open the ZynAddSubFX interface from inside LMMS.